# Is returning list of app_name + codename of permissions for currently logged in user a security risk in django?

Tags: python, django, security, django-rest-framework

I have an app named "todos" and inside this app I have a permission code named "add_todo", Is it a bad idea to return app name + code name(todos.add_todo) as a mechanism to control which buttons and UI to show to user in the Frontend?

I currently wrote an endpoint that returns all of the user's permissions as a list in this format: "app_name.permission__codename". I was wondering whether this would pose a security risk or not. Also it's worth noting that only currently logged in user can see his/her own permissions.

Comment: You can just return the label of permissions not to which app it belongs. That way users only get the see humain readable permissions only.

Comment: @Ahtisham Correct, but duplicate permission names can exist in different apps, Though in the end I decided to expose permission code names of a specific app instead of every single app and removed the app name as you said from the beginning of the strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no security issue but prefered way is to return action + app_name. if you look at permission model it has `content_type` that directs to app's model.

So your codename will be:

```
can_add_todos
can_delete_todos
```

And name would be caps of first letter of each word and space instead of underscopes similar example is from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/#programmatically-creating-permissions)